# How to forward a cookie from an API gateway to a service in Go?

Tags: go, cookies, middleware

I have a set of microservices and an API gateway that takes care of basic middleware like authorization in this case.

The idea is to validate the request as it is received by the gateway, if everything is okay, set the cookie so that it's accessible and read by the microservice.

I use the standard way to set a cookie:

```
http.SetCookie(w, &myCookie)
```

And then another handlerFunc is added to the chain that leads directly to the microservice.

CURLing this request makes it clear that the SetCookie directive is correctly configured but it's not immediately available in the microservice. In Postman and the browser, quite expectedly, the request works the second time when the cookie is set on the client.

But how do I achieve this so that the first middleware sets the cookie that then exists at the time when the second middleware starts validation?

Thanks!

Comment: is your first service header is `SetCookie` in header, but second service need "Cookie", So you can't use cookie, just use a othser key what you like